# Cobertura Issue with Autowired Classes

Tags: java, spring, cobertura, java-6

I am having some issues with Cobertura not counting code coverage for AutoWired Classes. I have a class layout like so:

```
class StartClass {

   @Autowired
   DeleteHandlerInterface handler;

   // function to call handler
}

class SoftDeleteHandlerImpl implements DeleteHandlerInterface {

   @Resource(name = "name")
   AnotherClassInterface  impl;

   @Autowired
   DataLayerInterface db;

   // function to do work
   impl.callFunction();
   db.delete();
}
```

It turns out Cobertura is able to determine coverage for StartClass and DataLayerInterface.  But it is saying 0% coverage for SoftDeleteHandlerImpl and AnotherClassInterface.  Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Are you using aspect-J weaving? If so, I find for integration tests runtime weaving works best.

Comment: How do I use runtime weaving with aspect-J?

Comment: Are you sure you're using AspectJ style weaving? By default Spring just falls back to dynamic proxies and cglib. . If you are its a cmd-line argument to the JVM:  -javaagent: <pathToAspectj>/lib/aspectjweaver.jar  (You can set this in your IDE's test config)

Comment: AspectJ-weaving does unlock some powerful features, such as the ability to do DI on non-container managed classes - like entities that come out of session factory, thus avoid the anaemic object anti-pattern.

Comment: It looks like the code is using aspect J as found the following in the spring-configuration. <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true" />.  I am assuming I need to try proxy-target-class="true" to leverage the cglib?

Comment: On reflection this doesn't look like a weaving problem. Sorry. This problem usually gives partially uncovered lines, but you have 0%. Have you tried Up/downgrading cobertura? This has worked for me in the past. (I'm my case downgraded)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're code really doesn't pass through the handler function. In the code you put here there's no method or method calls so it's hard to understand. But add a break-point and see if you really get to the handler class (or add log line if you can't debug).

Comment: I know for a fact the code is passing through my handler functions due to my logging.